# How to execute stored Proc / Function from different database (like Oracle/Postgress/etc) in Nestjs without any ORM

Tags: node.js, database, stored-procedures, nestjs, typeorm

I would like to execute stored proc / function / select query in different database (Oracle, Postgress, etc ) from NestJS without ORM.

An API is written in Nest JS.
It is expected to execute stored proc, function, select query in different database (like Oracle, Postgress, etc).

typeORM sample is provided and is generally used for CRUD. I prefer to avoid any ORM.

I would execute different stored proc /  query for different database and return the result.
I would like to abstract the database cal and return the result.
Please advise

Comment: I assume you're trying to avoid the baggage that comes with an ORM, right? You could try something like Knex.js, but even that comes with its own drawbacks. You might be best off writing your own abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to integrate mysql into nest without an orm, but if what you want is to avoid creating the entities but use the orm connection and consume the store procedure directly, you can do it this way, without having to create the entities, calling the EntityManager

```
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        private manager:EntityManager
    ) { }


    getProducts(){
        return this.manager.query(`CALL  SP_GET_PRODUCTS`)
    }
}
```